# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function flask-restful API

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-restful

I have created a flask application, it runs well when I type flask run in my pipenv shell terminal.
However, when I create the pytest coverage, it gives me an Assertion Error.

This is the error I got from my pytest:

```
=========================================================================================short test summary info =========================================================================================
ERROR test/test_landing.py::test_login - AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: brandlistapi
```

I tried retracing back to the error and tweaking the endpoints in the flask's _*init*_.py but still received the same error. Below are the codes for my routes and brands API: 
*routes.py*

```
def initialize_route(api):
    #Brand Routes
    api.add_resource(BrandListApi, '/api/brand/')
    api.add_resource(BrandApi, '/api/brand/<id>')
...
```

*brands.py*

```
class BrandListApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        brandList=getAll()
        return brandListReponseSchema.dump(brandList)
    
    def post(self):
        errors=createBrandRequestSchema.validate(request.get_json())
        if errors:
            return Response(status=400)
        else:
            createBrandRequest=createBrandRequestSchema.load(request.get_json())
            print(createBrandRequest, file=sys.stdout)
            create(createBrandRequest)
            return Response(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it turns out I had my fix is from the _*init*_.py

Initially it was:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
def create_app(test_config=None):
...
   return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

I changed it to:

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
   app = Flask(__name__)
   ...
   return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = create_app()
   app.run()
```

I am still learning haha